# IDE gets corrupt after debugging in Visual Studio 2003

Tags: visual-studio, crash

My solution currently contains 20 projects in total.  These are all window
applications.

But lately after my OS(Windows XP SP3) downloaded updates from Microsoft and after adding just one window form in one of the projects, VS 2003 IDE starts crashing when trying to debug the solution. After crashing VS needs to be reinstall....

ANY advice that might save me from having to reinstall VS2003 over and over?thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd disable all addons you might have installed and see if that helps (VS is usually quite stable, but some addons are not). If so, re-enable them one by one to find which one causes the problem

If that doesn't help, see if you can re-create the crash with a minimal solution, and if you can, it might be worth talking with MS about it, their [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/) website might be a good place to start.

Please note, if you edit your question to give more specific information (VS version & edition, what projects you're using etc) someone might be able to give a more specific answer, but I think with that generic question, you'll only get generic answers.

Comment: I also encountered same scenario. But in my case, I'm sure I haven't installed any addons.

Comment: @BOGZ: You might be out of luck with regards to contacting MS then, the mainstream support for VS2003 ended at 14/10/2008. However, it might still be worth trying to re-create the problem with a minimal solution, since then you might be able to find what is making it crash and you might be able to change that in your bigger solution.

Comment: . ill just try to recreate the problem.. or try to restore my computer to an earlier time... and we'll see how it can help...